# PHP mysql recursive function array_unshift

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have problem with recursive function in PHP. I call function and get row from database, than I put the row into array and I call function again to get other rows, who are conected with the row... Problem is, that array_unshift save only first row and other not. What is the problem. Thank you for your answers.

```
    public static function nahrejZpravy($responseTable, $responseId){
    $return = Array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Zpravy WHERE responseTable = '$responseTable' AND responseId = '$responseId'";
    $result = query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_unshift($return, $row);
        Zpravy::nahrejZpravy('Zpravy', $row['id']);
    }  
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: You should add PHP tag for more assistance

Comment: Why do you need that, at the end you want all of the info in one array? Can't you just have `while($row = ....) { $rows[] = $row } return $rows`. In your occasion you want to iterate each time to add the next id in the where clause until select all rows by id, which completely means for me you can get rid of it?

Comment: Why? I have Zpravy database table. Here I have some text... and defined, which message if before this message. So I took data from database for message and than I took them for the message before... Than I save it all into array and in View I´m going through the array and write messages.

Comment: Well, You will query your database with every $row['id'] you would find. However, if you want to stick to your way, first check what does $row outputs, what kind of array it is? Maybe you would need to iterate through it once more and save the values via array_unshift. If doesn't help maybe giving us the var_dump of $row and of the method itself will be good

Comment: Not every $row['id'], but only with for example ids 2,3,11,18. I will get rows for this ids and I want to save it into one array. Why? what is bad on my code? Why it saves only first row?

Comment: Don't do this, recursion and database queries don't go well together.

Answer (score 1):

You would actually need something like this:

```
<?php

function getResponsesRecursive($responseTable, $responseId) {
    $responses = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Zpravy WHERE responseTable = '$responseTable' AND responseId = '$responseId'";
    $result = query($query);
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $row['responses'] = getResponsesRecursive($row['table'], $row['id']);
        $responses[] = $row;
    }
    return $responses;
}
```

exaple:

```
$myArr = getResponsesRecursive('table', 0);

$myArr = arrary(
    array(
        'id'    =>  1,
        'table' =>  'table-name',
        'responses' =>  array(
            ...
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function getResponsesRecursive($responseTable, $responseId) {
    $responses = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Zpravy WHERE responseTable = '$responseTable' AND responseId = '$responseId'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $row['responses'] = getResponsesRecursive($row['table'], $row['id']);
        $responses[] = $row;
    }
    return $responses;
}
?>
```